# ASP.NET MVC3 Sending Multiple forms from the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

There are similar posts out there but they do not seem to represent my situation. Apologies in advance if this is a re-post.

I have my view as

```
@FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles:1,allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:true,includeFormTag:true, uploadText: "Upload" )

@model IEnumerable<EpubsLibrary.Models.Partner>
@{ using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Epub")) 
   {
        @Html.DropDownList("PartnerID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Partners, "None")
        <input type="submit" value="send" id="pickPartner" hidden="hidden"/>
   }        
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".file-upload-buttons input").click(function () {
        $("#pickPartner").click();
    });
</script>
```

my controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload, FormCollection collection)
{
    int selectedPartner, count =0;
    //int selectedPartner = int.Parse(collection["PartnerID"]);
    if(!int.TryParse(collection["PartnerID"], out selectedPartner))
    {
        selectedPartner = 0;
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "You must pick a publishing agency");
    }
    IList<Partner> p = r.ListPartners();
    ViewBag.Partners = new SelectList(p.AsEnumerable(), "PartnerID", "Name", selectedPartner);

    //make sure files were selected for upload 
    if (fileUpload != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileUpload.Count(); i++)
        {
            //make sure every file selected != null
            if (fileUpload.ElementAt(i) != null)
            {
                count++;
                var file = fileUpload.ElementAt(i);
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    // need to modify this for saving the files to the server
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/uploads"), Guid.NewGuid() + "-" + fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "You must upload at least one file!");
    }
    return View();
}
```

I am using the file upload helper from Microsoft Web Helpers to upload files. The problem I am having is the helper created a form and I have another form I need to submit data from as well on the same page.

I thought I could link the submit buttons so that when you click upload it also sent the other form data but the data is not being sent. Each form works independently of the other with no issue but I need them to work together. Any advice would be appreciated.

Ok I updated the view with

```
@model IEnumerable<EpubsLibrary.Models.Partner>
@{ using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Epub")) 
   {
        @Html.DropDownList("PartnerID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Partners, "None")
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles: 1, allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: true, includeFormTag: false, uploadText: "Upload")
        <input type="submit" value="send" id="pickPartner"/>
   }        
}
```

But now the file data does not seem to be getting passed anymore.

-- Update --

I have made the following changes. 
The view now looks like

```
@model IEnumerable<EpubsLibrary.Models.Partner>
@{ using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Epub", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {
        @Html.DropDownList("PartnerID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Partners, "None")
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles: 1, allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: true, includeFormTag: false, uploadText: "Upload")
        <input type="submit" value="send" id="pickPartner"/>
   }        
}
```

and the controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload, int PartnerID = 0)
        //public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload, FormCollection collection)
        {
            int count =0;
            IList<Partner> p = r.ListPartners();
            ViewBag.Partners = new SelectList(p.AsEnumerable(), "PartnerID", "Name", PartnerID);
            //make sure files were selected for upload 
            if (fileUpload != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fileUpload.Count(); i++)
                {
                    //make sure every file selected != null
                    if (fileUpload.ElementAt(i) != null)
                    {
                        count++;
                        var file = fileUpload.ElementAt(i);
                        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                            // need to modify this for saving the files to the server
                            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/uploads"), Guid.NewGuid() + "-" + fileName);
                            file.SaveAs(path);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (count == 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "You must upload at least one file!");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to figure out how the file data is getting sent over in the post (if it is) so I can save the files.

-- Final Update with Answer --

Well the problem turned out to be two fold.. 1st the issue with `@FileUpload` and needing to set `includeFormTag: false`

The other problem I discovered was I needed to make sure in my `@Html.BeginForm` I included `FormMethod.Post` This was discovered when the fileUpload count kept coming back as 0. I ran the profiler on firebug and it pointed out that the file data was not actually getting posted. Here is the corrected code below.

my view

```
@model IEnumerable<EpubsLibrary.Models.Partner>
@{ using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Epub", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {
        @Html.DropDownList("PartnerID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Partners, "None")
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles: 1, allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: true, includeFormTag: false, uploadText: "Upload")
        <input type="submit" value="send" id="pickPartner"/>
   }        
}
```

my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload, int PartnerID = 0)        
{
    int count =0;
    IList<Partner> p = r.ListPartners();
    ViewBag.Partners = new SelectList(p.AsEnumerable(), "PartnerID", "Name", PartnerID);
    //make sure files were selected for upload 
    if (fileUpload != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileUpload.Count(); i++)
        {
            //make sure every file selected != null
            if (fileUpload.ElementAt(i) != null)
            {
                count++;
                var file = fileUpload.ElementAt(i);
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    // need to modify this for saving the files to the server
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/App_Data/uploads"), Guid.NewGuid() + "-" + fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "You must upload at least one file!");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Thank you @Jay and @Vasile Bujac for your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set IncludeFormTag to `false` and put it inside your other form `using`.

```
@model IEnumerable<EpubsLibrary.Models.Partner>
@{ using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Epub")) 
   {
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles:1,allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:true,includeFormTag:false, uploadText: "Upload" )

        @Html.DropDownList("PartnerID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Partners, "None")
        <input type="submit" value="send" id="pickPartner" hidden="hidden"/>
   }        
}
```

Update:
Try changing the signature of your view to this:

```
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload, int PartnerID = 0)
```

Check the overloads for `FileUpload.GetHtml` and see if there is a parameter to set the field name for your file uploads. Previously it was just the files being uploaded, now its files and a parameter, so naming becomes more important.

Comment: Please see edit above. The file data does not seem to be getting passed the same way anymore now that I made that change. Thank you.

Comment: This is setting the partnerID correctly without sending the FormCollection but for some reason the fileUpload.Count() is still 0 even when I select multiple files.

Comment: Along with Vasile suggestion, try to fire up Fiddler and see what values get posted with your files. I would imagine if the files were working before, they should continue to work.

Comment: sorry I am not familiar with Fiddler what does it do?

Comment: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a debugging tool that will capture web packets being sent back and forth between the browser and server. Great for debugging issues like this.

Comment: It captures web traffic so that you can inspect raw HTTP requests to understand where the issue lies. However, I think you could firstly check if there are any files in Request.Files collection...

Comment: @Vasile Bujac, he says the `.Count()` property was 0. So they may be getting posted, but probably not under the name `fileUpload`.

Comment: I am at a loss on how to check for what name they are getting sent under.

Comment: under fiddler if I look at the session and "textview" it shows PartnerID=312&fileUpload=crashreporter.exe

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same form for dropdownlist and file inputs. You can do this by putting the FileUpload helper inside the form, and setting "includeFormTag" parameter to false.

```
@model IEnumerable<EpubsLibrary.Models.Partner>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Epub")) {
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles:1,allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:true,includeFormTag:false, uploadText: "Upload" )
        @Html.DropDownList("PartnerID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Partners, "None")
        <input type="submit" value="send" id="pickPartner" hidden="hidden"/>
   }
```

Comment: Please see edit above. The file data does not seem to be getting passed the same way anymore now that I made that change. Thank you.

Comment: maybe it's a model binding issue (what names does your helper generates for your input?), did you check the Request.Files collection to see if any data is passsed?